# Jmeter: Comparing 2 JSON Extractor Variables and updating .jtl accordingly

Tags: jmeter

**Scenario**: I have 3 HTTP requests to make as follows:

**Step1**: Make request1 and use JSON extractor to extract a value from JSON response and store it in a variable say x

**Step2**: Make request2 and wait for 2minutes(I'm using Constant Timer).

**Step3**: Make request3 and use JSON extractor to extract a value from JSON response and store it in a variable say y

**Step4**: Compare 'x' and 'y' and Pass the test in jtl file if y > x else fail.

***Issue***: I'm not able to find out the way to complete step4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x and y are numbers insider JMeter variables, for step 4 use [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a post processor of request3,

In code convert variables to numbers and compare it as and if `y >x` fail the sampler:

```
x = vars.get("x");
y = vars.get("y");

if (Integer.parseInt(x) >=  Integer.parseInt(y)) {
    log.info("x is bigger than y, continue test");
} else {
    prev.setSuccessful(false);    
}
```

Example in Java/Beanshell language, but you can use groovy also.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how can I make the result file(.jtl file) to contain failed result?

Comment: `prev.setSuccessful(false)` mark httprequest3 as failure also in result file